# Selenium Webdriver_Java_How to Call Mutiple Class into One Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I stuck at point i have one website for example (http://newtours.demoaut.com/) and for that i have created multiple classes likes: 
App_Login(),
App_Dashboard(),
App_FliReservation(),
Cancel_Flight(); 
So want to call above all classes into single class .
can someone guide me on these.

**Script sample**
 App_Login() class

```html
public class App_login {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  
  WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

 }

}
```

and i want to call above class into following class

```html
public class Mercurywebapp {
@Test
public void supp_onboarding() throws Exception {

App_Login();

}

public void App_Login() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
}
}
```

when i run above class (i.e.Mercurywebapp) then getting blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Create another instances of all the  Classes in the MercuryWebapp

Depends on the access modifiers for the classes
e.g

App_Login testObject = new App_Login();